# Set same date in diferent inputs with multiple date format

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two inputs with the same date, but i want to separate the day from the month and year. When select one, updates the other... I have almost done it but i have some problem that i dont understand...

There is a exemple,

http://jsfiddle.net/m99xD/1/

Tkhs in advance

Comment: what problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? When you select a day, should the month/year be updated too (based on your selected day on the left), or should it remain the same?

Comment: Why do want us to assume your problem? Why not straight away mention in the question?

Comment: sry i was not very clear. The date on others inputs are not assumed. When i click in the day, i want to the other input assume that value.

Comment: @Ramos my first answer was based on the other assumption. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: For some reason, `minDate` is causing problems, so I'd suggest removing it first if you don't need it. When you select a date, and your date format only shows part of it (days, or month/year), only that part is taken into account, which is not what you want. A workaround for it would be to change the dateFormat right before the dialog opens, and change it back after selection:

```
$( ".departDateMonthYear" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat:"M yy" ,     
    hideIfNoPrevNext:true ,
    //minDate:0,
    beforeShow:function() {
        // Change dateFormat for a full format, so the correct date can be selected
        $(this).datepicker("option","dateFormat","dd/mm/yy");
    },
    onSelect:function () {
        var dat_thisDate = $( this ).datepicker( 'getDate' );
        dat_thisDate.setDate( dat_thisDate.getDate() );
        $( ".departDateDay" ).datepicker( "setDate" , dat_thisDate );

        // Change the format back to the original, after the date is set
        $(this).datepicker("option",{
            dateFormat:"M yy",
            monthNamesShort:arr_monthsNameAbr // bonus: display using your localized month names
        });
    }
});
```

The input for days is analogous. [Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/9CvSC/) on jsFiddle.

Comment: That doesnt worked, it appears that the value is not assumed by the other input.

Comment: Yeah, I answered that based on my assumption that the inputs were independent...

Comment: it worked... =) thks very much +1